# how to convert a given a letter in a string from lower case to upper case in ruby

Tags: ruby

Given a string, let's see "rxrx" , how can I convert the string into "rXrX", put it another way:
turn all the lower case 'x'  in the string into the upper case 'X' in ruby? Thanks in advance

Comment: Um... Have you tried regular expressions?

Comment: No need for regex. This is precisely what `tr` is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
"rxrx".gsub(/(x)/) { |s| s.upcase }
```

The only reason I suggest this instead of just normal substitution (`gsub("x", "X")`) is because it'd work well if there were more than one character you wanted to make uppercase:

```
"rxbrx".gsub(/([xb])/) { |s| s.upcase }
```

Comment: So does #tr ; "rxbrx".tr('xb', 'XB')

Answer (score 6):

"tr" method of String class should work for you.

```
irb> "rxxr".tr('x', 'X')
irb> "rXXr"
```